# Why does %H fail in BQ parse dates?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

When I run:

```
SELECT
  CELL_ID,
  EXTRACT(date
  FROM
    TIMESTAMP( PARSE_DATE('%y%m%dT%H%M%S',
        EVENT_TM) )) AS date,
  EXTRACT(hour
  FROM
    TIMESTAMP( PARSE_DATE('%y%m%dT%H%M%S',
        EVENT_TM ))) AS hour,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CELL_ID ) AS cnt
FROM
  `cells.covid`
GROUP BY
  CELL_ID,
  date,
  hour
```

this returns an error `Invalid format: %H is not allowed for the DATE type.`

Answer (score 1):

`DATE`s don't have time components.  Use `DATETIME`s or `TIMESTAMP`s instead.

Presumably, you want:

```
DATE(PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%y%m%dT%H%M%S', EVENT_TM))
```

Note:  This assumes that `EVENT_TM` is in UTC; if it is in another timezone, you can use a third argument to provide that:

```
DATE(PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%y%m%dT%H%M%S', EVENT_TM), 'America/New_York')
```